# What do shoes do?

Tags: run-sackboy-run

In *Run Sackboy! Run!* there seem to be two types of upgrade - the score multiplier (denoted by the golden Sackboy head) and the...shoe thing. These can be seen below in the upper-left hand corner. From what I can see the game doesn't describe what this does.

[image: "Kangaroo"? More like bunny in a diaper.]

I'm guessing this increases running speed or something like that but in an endless running/jumping game, isn't that counter-productive? Surely I would want this to be as low as possible, to help me avoid obstacles. Furthermore, I've got a +4 Shoe multiplier and I haven't noticed the running speed varying at all, though that could just be me.

Does anybody know what the shoes do?